# How to flush DNS cache while resolving a service using NSNetServiceBrowser in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, caching, nsnetservicebrowser

I am resolving a udp service using NSNetServiceBrowser. It is working fine but if I disconnect my service then also it discovers it.
I got a link which says it remains visible for a while because  the DNS record reaches its time-to-live interval and disappears.
link - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/faq.html    (point number 4)

How can I flush the cache so that service would be unreachable?